# How to exclude a dynamically changing list of fields from the dto using Jackson?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, quarkus, jackson-databind

Given a dynamically changing list of fields that should be available in final response. The main task is how to exclude all other fields from DTO using jackson.

*For example*:

**Sample DTO**

```
Sample DTO {
  firstName: <String>,
  lastName: <String>,
  address: <String>,
  email: <String>,
}
```

**Available fields 1** - ["firstName", "lastName", "address"] at the moment 1

**Sample DTO final response 1**

```
Sample DTO final response {
  firstName: <String>,
  lastName: <String>,
  address: <String>
}
```

**Available fields 2** - ["firstName", "email"] at the moment 2

**Sample DTO final response 2**

```
Sample DTO final response {
  firstName: <String>,
  email: <String>,
}
```

Right now i have this solution:

**SampleDTO**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonFilter("myFilter")
public class SampleDTO {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String address;
    String email;
}
```

**CustomObjectMapper**

```
public class CustomObjectMapper {

    // Replaces the CDI producer for ObjectMapper built into Quarkus
    @Singleton
    @Produces
    ObjectMapper objectMapper(Instance<ObjectMapperCustomizer> customizers) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // Custom `ObjectMapper`

        // Apply all ObjectMapperCustomizer beans (incl. Quarkus)
        for (ObjectMapperCustomizer customizer : customizers) {
            customizer.customize(mapper);
        }

        return mapper;
    }
}
```

**RegisterCustomModuleCustomizer**

```
@Singleton
public class RegisterCustomModuleCustomizer implements ObjectMapperCustomizer {

    @Inject
    MockService mockService;

    public void customize(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("myFilter", new PropertyFilter(mockService));

        mapper.setFilterProvider(filters);
    }
}
```

**PropertyFilter**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PropertyFilter extends SimpleBeanPropertyFilter {

    MockService mockService;

    @Override
    public void serializeAsField(Object pojo, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider, PropertyWriter writer) throws Exception {
        if (include(writer)) {
            List<String> availableFields = mockService.getAvailableFields();
            if (availableFields.contains(writer.getName())) {
                writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
            }
        } else if (!jgen.canOmitFields()) { // since 2.3
            writer.serializeAsOmittedField(pojo, jgen, provider);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean include(BeanPropertyWriter writer) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean include(PropertyWriter writer) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**MockService**

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MockService {
    public List<String> getAvailableFields() {
        return Arrays.asList("firstName", "lastName", "address");
    }
}
```

This solution works but there is in one bad moment that for each field a method from the service is called. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: What determines which properties are supposed to be included in the response?

Comment: In my example, this is `MockService.getAvailableFields()`. But in fact this list is taken from the database and `Arrays.asList("firstName", "lastName", "address")` replaced to `availableFiledsRepository.findAll()`

Comment: I was going to suggest using `@JsonAnyGetter` but that won't really work with a "service" providing those property names.